# modules defined outside src/app showing error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './' in"

Tags: angular, typescript, module

[image: this is my project structure]

I wanted to import collegeDuniyApp module in app.module.ts but it is showing me this error. I have my tsconfig file configured like this [image: tsconfig.json]. tsconfig.app.json is this [image: tsonfig.app.json] and here is app.module.ts[image] and here is collegeDuniyaApp.module.ts. I am importing collegeDuniyaApp.module using collegeDuniyaApp.ts [image: collegeDuniyaApp.ts] and then calling collegeDuniyaApp.ts in app.module.ts.

I tried many ways but same error[image: Error] comes again and again. here is the carCard component [image: carCard component].

here is the collegeduniya.module.ts[image: collegeduniya.module.ts]

Comment: And why do you have modules outside of the app folder?

Comment: Don't just downvote it/ if you don't know the answer. 
@JosefKatič I want to keep this outside and use it as separate module and develop similar modules like collegeduniya module and develop it.

Comment: can someone please help me in what is wrong in module instead of downvoting it

Comment: Ok, I can't even downvote I just didn't know the reason for separating them

Comment: Could you please add here the code from one of the files causing that error. (carCard or something like that)

Comment: @JosefKatič Its not for you. I am sorry. I am sharing

Comment: How the component path look in the `collegeDuniya.module.ts`?

Comment: I added the screenshot. Please have a look

Comment: Do you want to use the components outside of this module?

Comment: Try removing the `collegeDuniyaAppModule`  from `exports: [collegeDuniyaAppModule]` because you already export the module by the line under `export class CollegeDuniyaAppModule {}`

Comment: No I want to use collegeduniyAppmodule's component's by adding the  collegeduniyAppmodule  in appModule.ts. Okay let me remove me it from the exports.

Comment: You can export component like this but not module. So in your case change this `exports: [collegeDuniyaAppModule];` to this `exports: [collegeDuniyaComponent];`

Comment: Is there is a way to make this happen. I am looking for a way to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the mistake is in your `collegeduniya.module.ts`. Because there you are exporting module in modules `exports: [];`

Try to update the module to this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {CollegeDuniyaComponent} from './college-duniya.component';
import { CarCardComponent } from './car-card/car-card.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [CollegeDuniyaComponent, CarCardComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    CollegeDuniyaComponent,
  // And all components you want to use in app.component.ts
  ]
})
export class CollegeDuniyaModule { }
```

The problem can be also caused by your tsconfig.json. When I wanted to define short paths I have had to restart the IDE.

Comment: Yes thats what I think. I have removed the component from the exports but still getting the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem was angular has a structure. If I wanted use something like a second module.
One can use a angular library or there are different kind of modules specified by angular.
Both are useful and depends on how you want to use the module.
In my case I had to use it as a library as I wanted to make a package out of it and use it as a module in other modules.

All this was just for learning.
Thanks Everyone.